# What corpus-based writing tools do you use?

Tags: style, tools

I'm searching for a tool that would make real-time suggestions based on "real world" text. The only corpus-based tool I know of is *Writefull* - does anybody know of any others?

Comment: Could you define a "corpus-based writing tool"? and why would you call it an exception?

Comment: I think they're talking about something that will examine your work for grammar, cliche's, and etc.  Writefull seems to be something like that.  I think they're using one dollar words when nickel words would have worked just fine... for example... "Does anyone know of a writing tool that will search my document for problem phrases?"  They're using the word successions like a verb, but I think it's just the plural of a noun.  [Shrug]

Comment: "Corpus based" seems to me to mean that the software has performed automatic analysis of lots of documents, and can point out where your writing follows patterns that are either too common (which would help spot cliches, as @dowhilenot suggests) or too rare (which may help spot grammar errors, or misuse of words).

Answer (score 1):

There is [Grammarly.](https://www.grammarly.com)  It is an app which can be used to check spelling and grammar typed into a browser; whether it is for webmail, website contact form or blogging site.  It can check your grammar when typing a question or answer here.

There is also a Grammarly plugin for use with Microsoft Office.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE _Chris_! If you have time please check out the [help] and the [tour]. Have fun!

Comment: And what am I to gain from following these links @WhiteEagle?

Comment: They are simply a tour to website and what is on topic. It was meant as a welcome to site and a quick way to get to some important pages.

Comment: Ah ok :-) I see

Answer (score 1):

Grammarly is a great tool for grammar problems (hence the name) and thus works across the board for many types of writing. If are doing any fiction writing, check out [AutoCrit](http://autocrit.com). You pay a monthly cost to use it and enter your story directly into the web browser and it brings up problems in your writing like using too many adverbs, lack of sentence length variation, etc.